# NodeJs/Express/MongoDb - ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

hope you spent really good holidays

I'm following a tutorial online but i've an error that the teacher doesn't have in the video (i also copy his code but same error).

I have this error only with the "PUT" function but the strange thing is that it updates well in mongoDB. It just gives me an error.

Here's my code:
user.controller.js

```
const UserModel = require("../models/user.model");
const ObjectID = require("mongoose").Types.ObjectId;

module.exports.getAllUsers = async (req, res) => {
  const users = await UserModel.find().select("-password");
  res.status(200).json(users);
};

module.exports.userInfo = (req, res) => {
  if (!ObjectID.isValid(req.params.id))
    return res.status(400).send("ID unknown : " + req.params.id);

  UserModel.findById(req.params.id, (err, docs) => {
    if (!err) res.send(docs);
    else console.log("Id unknown" + err);
  }).select("-password");
};

module.exports.updateUser = async (req, res) => {
  if (!ObjectID.isValid(req.params.id))
    return res.status(400).send("ID unknown : " + req.params.id);

  try {
    await UserModel.findOneAndUpdate(
      { _id: req.params.id },
      {
        $set: {
          bio: req.body.bio,
        },
      },
      { new: true, upsert: true, setDefaultsOnInsert: true },
      (err, docs) => {
        if (!err) return res.send(docs);
        if (err) return res.status(500).send({ message: err });
      }
    );
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(500).json({ message: err });
  }
};

module.exports.deleteUser = async (req, res) => {
  if (!ObjectID.isValid(req.params.id))
    return res.status(400).send("ID unknown : " + req.params.id);

  try {
    await UserModel.remove({ _id: req.params.id }).exec();
    res.status(200).json({ message: "Successfully deleted. " });
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(500).json({ message: err });
  }
};
```

user.model.js :

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const { isEmail } = require("validator");
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    pseudo: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      minlength: 3,
      maxlength: 55,
      unique: true,
      trim: true,
    },
    email: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      validate: [isEmail],
      lowercase: true,
      trim: true,
    },
    password: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      max: 1024,
      minlength: 6,
    },
    picture: {
      type: String,
      default: "./upload/profil/random-user.png",
    },
    bio: {
      type: String,
      max: 1024,
    },
    followers: {
      type: [String],
    },
    following: {
      type: [String],
    },
    likes: {
      type: [String],
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);

// playfunction before save into db
userSchema.pre("save", async function (next) {
  const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt();
  this.password = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, salt);
  next();
});

// Export user
const UserModel = mongoose.model("user", userSchema);

module.exports = UserModel;
```

Here the error in terminal:

```
(node:16752) [MONGODB DRIVER] Warning: collection.remove is deprecated. Use deleteOne, deleteMany, or bulkWrite instead. (Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created) events.js:292
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:558:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (D:\Programmation\mern\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:771:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (D:\Programmation\mern\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:170:12)
    at ServerResponse.json (D:\Programmation\mern\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:267:15)
    at ServerResponse.send (D:\Programmation\mern\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:158:21)
    at D:\Programmation\mern\controllers\user.controller.js:33:30
    at D:\Programmation\mern\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:4912:18
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:75:11) Emitted 'error' event on Function instance at:
    at D:\Programmation\mern\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:4914:15
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:75:11) {   code: 'ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT' }
```

And here the error in PostMan:
(for information, if i put a wrong id in postman i've my error as expected "ID unknown:" ...)

```
{
    "message": {
        "originalStack": "Error\n    at model.Query._wrappedThunk [as _findOneAndUpdate] (D:\\Programmation\\mern\\node_modules\\mongoose\\lib\\helpers\\query\\wrapThunk.js:25:28)\n    at D:\\Programmation\\mern\\node_modules\\kareem\\index.js:279:20\n    at _next (D:\\Programmation\\mern\\node_modules\\kareem\\index.js:103:16)\n    at D:\\Programmation\\mern\\node_modules\\kareem\\index.js:508:38\n    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:75:11)"
    }
}
```

Earlier i change :

```
catch (err) {
    return res.status(500).json({ message: err });
  }"
```

to a simple

```
 console.log(err)
```

And had this error in the terminal(but not in Postman anymore):

```
MongooseError: Query was already executed: user.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: new ObjectId("61363178c0b345e93...
    at model.Query._wrappedThunk [as _findOneAndUpdate] (D:\Programmation\mern\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\query\wrapThunk.js:21:19)
    at D:\Programmation\mern\node_modules\kareem\index.js:279:20
    at _next (D:\Programmation\mern\node_modules\kareem\index.js:103:16)
    at D:\Programmation\mern\node_modules\kareem\index.js:508:38
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:75:11) {
  originalStack: 'Error\n' +
    '    at model.Query._wrappedThunk [as _findOneAndUpdate] (D:\\Programmation\\mern\\node_modules\\mongoose\\lib\\helpers\\query\\wrapThunk.js:25:28)\n' +
    '    at D:\\Programmation\\mern\\node_modules\\kareem\\index.js:279:20\n' +
    '    at _next (D:\\Programmation\\mern\\node_modules\\kareem\\index.js:103:16)\n' +
    '    at D:\\Programmation\\mern\\node_modules\\kareem\\index.js:508:38\n' +
    '    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:75:11)'
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help !

Have a good day :)

EDIT: After the 1st answer from mohammad Naimi:

I add else, and i still have the same issue, mongodb is actually update but i've the error message

here's my updated code

```
const UserModel = require("../models/user.model");
const ObjectID = require("mongoose").Types.ObjectId;

module.exports.getAllUsers = async (req, res) => {
  const users = await UserModel.find().select("-password");
  res.status(200).json(users);
};

module.exports.userInfo = (req, res) => {
  if (!ObjectID.isValid(req.params.id))
    return res.status(400).send("ID unknown : " + req.params.id);
  else {
    UserModel.findById(req.params.id, (error, docs) => {
      if (!error) res.send(docs);
      else console.log("Id unknown" + error);
    }).select("-password");
  }
};

module.exports.updateUser = async (req, res) => {
  if (!ObjectID.isValid(req.params.id))
    return res.status(400).send("ID unknown : " + req.params.id);
  else {
    try {
      await UserModel.findOneAndUpdate(
        { _id: req.params.id },
        {
          $set: {
            bio: req.body.bio,
          },
        },
        { new: true, upsert: true, setDefaultsOnInsert: true },
        (error, docs) => {
          if (!error) return res.send(docs);
          else {
            return res.status(500).send({ message: error });
          }
        }
      );
    } catch (error) {
      return res.status(500).json({ message: error });
    }
  }
};

module.exports.deleteUser = async (req, res) => {
  if (!ObjectID.isValid(req.params.id))
    return res.status(400).send("ID unknown : " + req.params.id);
  else {
    try {
      await UserModel.remove({ _id: req.params.id }).exec();
      res.status(200).json({ message: "Successfully deleted. " });
    } catch (error) {
      return res.status(500).json({ message: error });
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, so after multiple try and fails ! here's the answer : Use mongoose@5.10.6 and it should be good

Have an awesome day coder buddies

Answer (score 2):

1st solution: Downgrade your Mongoose version (to 5.10.13 for exemple)

2nd solution:  Don't use the callback function, use a `.then` instead (with Mongoose 6.0.13) :

---

```
 module.exports.updateUser = async (req, res) => {
  if (!ObjectID.isValid(req.params.id))
    return res.status(400).send("ID invalid : " + req.params.id);

  try {
    await UserModel.findOneAndUpdate(
      { _id: req.params.id },
      {
        $set: {
          bio: req.body.bio,
        },
      },
      { new: true, upsert: true, setDefaultsOnInsert: true }
    )
      .then((docs) => res.send(docs))
      .catch((err) => res.status(500).send({ message: err }));
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json({ message: err });
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so after multiple try and fails ! here's the answer : Use mongoose@5.10.6 and it should be good

Have an awesome day coder buddies

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer, i tried you but i still have the same issue

Answer (score 0):

I also experienced the same problem but what I erased the callback functions and instead I used the (then) instead of the callback functions

```
exports.likePost = async (req, res) => {
  if (!objectID.isValid(req.params.id))
    return res.status(400).send("ID unkonwn:" + req.params.id);
  try {
    // update for collection post
    await postModel.findByIdAndUpdate(
      req.params.id,
      {
        $addToSet: { likers: req.body.id }
      },
      { new: true }
      // update for colletcion users
    ).then(async (resp) => {
      await userModel.findOneAndUpdate(
        req.body.id,
        { $addToSet: { likes: req.params.id } },
        { new: true }
      ).then(data => {
        return res.status(201).json({ message: 'inserted with success' })
      });
    });   
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(400).send(error)
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use "mongoose@5.10.6" and your programm will work

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I also had the same error but after several searches, I found that instead of a callback function you have to use

```
.then((docs) => res.send(docs))
```

Comment: Benjamin, please write your answer in English, as Stack Overflow is an [English-only site](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297680).